# Can someone please explain this javascript code (related to ajax)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jwplayer

I am a little confused as to what the function below does. Would someone be able to explain the steps once "id" and "data" are entered?

```
function LoadPlayer(id,data) {
    $.ajax({
        url:Player,
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id,data:data}}).done(function(result{
            $('#'+id).html(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: It loads the player information using id and data variables via ajax call method POST, and update the html element that has id attribute equals to the id variable with result data from the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

It send a POST request using ajax, with Player object as its URL. The body data has an object with properties id and data. Once the ajax request is successful, it finds a dom element with ID id and writes its result from the request there.